# Python JSON assign data from API

Tags: python, json, wordpress

I have a py file to read data from Wordpress API and pass values to another fields of other API. When values are singles, i have no problem, but i don't know how make that:
When i read one field from the API, the states values, comes with code instead the text value. For example, when the text value in Wordpress is Barcelona, returns B, and i'll need that the value returned will be Barcelona.
One example of code with simple fields values:

```
oClienteT["Direcciones"] = []
oClienteT["Telefono"] = oClienteW["billing"]["phone"]
oClienteT["NombreFiscal"] = oClienteW["first_name"] " " oClienteW["last_name"]
oClienteT["Direcciones"].append( {
"Codigo" : oClienteW["id"],
"Nombre" : oClienteW["billing"]["first_name"],
"Apellidos" : oClienteW["billing"]["last_name"],
"Direccion" : oClienteW["billing"]["address_1"],
"Direccion2" : oClienteW["billing"]["address_2"],
"Poblacion" : oClienteW["billing"]["state"],
"Provincia" : oClienteW["billing"]["city"]
})
```

When billing city is Madrid and billing state is madrid, Wordpress returns Madrid and M
I need tell thst when Madrid, returns Madrid, and so on.

Comment: Can you add example API responses? Are the state codes just the first letter of the city or is there a different coding used?

Comment: Here is an example of what returns api call:
`{
"billing": {
"address_1": "C/GUSTAVO ADOLFO BECQUER, 4",
"city": "SEVILLA",
"state": "SE",
}`

Comment: when city="SEVILLA" state must write SEVILLA too instead SE, and the same with all the cities and states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just got solved it:

```
def initProvincias(self):
self.aProvincias['C']  = 'A Coruña'
self.aProvincias['VI']  = 'Álava'
def getProvincia(self , sCod ):
if not sCod in self.aProvincias:
_logger.info("PROVINCIA NO ENCONTRADA "+str(sCod))
return ""
return self.aProvincias[sCod]

"Provincia"     : self.getProvincia( oClienteW["shipping"]["state"] ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to convert to a JSON object before accessing fields `(data = json.loads(json_str))`

```
response = { "billing": { "address_1": "C/GUSTAVO ADOLFO BECQUER, 4", "city": "SEVILLA", "state": "SE"}}

print(response["billing"].get("address_1", None))
```